# Passing input into passwd using pipe

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, passwd

How can I pipe some input using `echo`, into program that requires user typing something two times?

for example

```
echo "somepassword"|passwd someuser
```

creates this error message

```
Enter new UNIX password: Retype new UNIX password: passwd: Authentication token manipulation error
passwd: password unchanged
```

because I didn't retyped password

Comment: Try using `expect/auto-expect` I guess right tool for you.

Comment: please don't do this. This command would be stored in the command history. Your password may be seen by all.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to send the password twice:

```
(echo 'somepassword'; echo 'somepassword') | passwd someuser
```

Answer (score 2):

As root you could try

```
echo "somepasswored" | passwd someuser --stdin
```

> --stdin
>                 This option is used to indicate that passwd  should  read  the  new
>                 password from standard input, which can be a pipe.

If you're not root then you should't be able to change some  other users password. If you really want to go through the whole business of providing 2 passwords the expect is a good tool to use.

Answer (score 2):

Can also do this

```
echo -e "currentPassword\nNewPassword\nNewPassword" | passwd
```

the -e will make echo actually use a new line, not just print \n 
This option is for when you need the current password before your new one
if the current password isnt needed, you can omit it.

```
echo -e "NewPassword\nNewPassword" | passwd
```

I also agree that this is bad practice for multiuse/public computers, but if you know what your doing, and have a good reason for it, this works.